# Is the suffix dot in "Mr." optional or required?

Tags: word-usage, periods

I am pretty sure I am aware of the meaning of "Mr.", which is a title used before the family name or full name in of a man who has no other title, or when talking to man who holds a particular official position.

source: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mr)

However, the usage of "Mr." or "Mr" confuses me a bit, that is whether the suffix dot "." in "Mr." is 
 optional or required.

I see both two forms are commonly used, Google Ngram shows that the former is more commonly used than the latter.

even Cambridge Dictionary uses both of them.

> Good afternoon, Mr Dawson.
>
> I’m afraid I can’t agree with what’s just been said, Mr. Chairman

Is it a matter of AmE vs. BrE or just something about style?

Comment: The 'suffix dot' is a full stop or period. I googled _full stop after mr_ and found lots of information.

Answer (score 6):

Purely style.  In British use the dot is usually omitted.  In American use the dot is usually included.

But unless you are required to follow a particular style guide, it doesn't matter. Do try to be consistent.

> British usage favours omitting the full stop in abbreviations which include the first and last letters of a single word, such as Mr, Mrs, Ms, Dr and St; American usage prefers (A) Mr., Mrs., Ms., Dr. and St., with full stops.

http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/capsandabbr/abbr

Answer (score 3):

> Should you write **Mr Smith** or **Mr. Smith**?
>   Should you write **Dr Jones** or **Dr. Jones**?
>
> If you're following US convention, put a period (full stop) after your contraction.
>
> If you're following UK convention, you have a choice whether to use a full stop (period) or not.
>
> Here's a useful guideline for *Brits*:
>
> If the last letter of a contraction is the same as the last letter of the whole word, then don't use a full stop (period).
>
> **For example:**
>   Mister -> Mr
>   (The last letters are the same.)
>
> Professor > Prof. 
>   (The last letters are different.)

This link might be helpful: https://www.dailywritingtips.com/does-mr-take-a-period/